# Understanding java compiler

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Assuming I have this two classes, in separate files:

```
public class Text
{
    public String _word;

    public Text(String w)
    {
        _word = w;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return _word;
    }

    public boolean equals (Text other)
    {
        return ((other!=null)&&(_word.equals(other._word)));

    }
    public boolean test (Text other)
    {
        return 1==1;

    }
}
```

2nd class:

```
public class Sentence
{
    public String _word;

    public Sentence(String w)
    {
        _word = w;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return _word;
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        return ((other!=null) && (other instanceof Sentence)
                &&  (_word.equals(((Sentence) other)._word)));
    }
}
```

And the following main:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

     Text y1 = new Text("abc");
     Sentence z1 = new Sentence ("abc");
     **
}
```

Let's say I run the following command where ** is:

```
System.out.println (y1.equals(z1));
```

Everything is ok, and it outputs "false".

But, if I run this command:

```
System.out.println (y1.test(z1));
```

The compiler screams "Sentence can not be converted to Text".

Two questions:

1. Why it works for equals but not for test? y1 is Text, so calling `y1.equlas()` calls to `equlas()` inside Text, and there it gets only Text as parameter.
2. If it DOES work, why the output is false? both "_word" set to "abc".

Thanks!

Comment: put this line in your `Word.equals` method `System.out.println("Word equals called");` and then run the test. See what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined an `equals(Text)` method in `Text`.  However, it doesn't override the existing `equals(Object)` method that it inherits from `Object`.  Because of this, your `equals(Text)` method overloads the `equals(Object)` method in `Object`.  Consequently, you can call `y1.equals(z1)`.  Because `z1` is a `Sentence`, the `equals(Object)` method is the one called.  The `Sentence` object matches `Object` but not `Text`.  The [`equals` method in `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) compares object references to see if they're identical.

> The `equals` method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns `true` if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value `true`).

They're not, so it returns `false`.

You've defined a `test(Text)` method in `Text`.  There are no other overloads available, and `Sentence` doesn't match `Text` at all, so the compiler complains.

Incidentally, the `equals(Object)` method you've defined in `Sentence` is a proper override of `equals`, checking for `null` and the class of the argument.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) class definition, you inherit this in all classes

> public boolean equals(Object obj)

In your case `y1.equals(z1)` is actually executed as `y1.equals( (Object) z1)`, a valid cast since all objects inherit `Object`. You then have the above method called.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Text.java you wanted to override `Object.equals(Object other)`, but instead of overriding you created an other method with the same name (`equals(Text other)`), but with different parameter type.

That is why `System.out.println (y1.equals(z1));` compiles: that equals call matches the signature `equals(Object)`, which method Text inherits from `Object`.

On the other hand, `System.out.println (y1.test(z1));` fails to compile, since `Text` has only 1 method with the name `test`, and its formal parameter type is `Text`, which doesn't match the type of the actual parameter (`Sentence`).